# How to show wind direction on a compass

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, compass-geolocation

I am working on a web application where I have to show the temperature, humidity, wind speed, wind direction etc. I am using google.visualization.Gauge() to show other things but I want to show wind direction on a compass. Does anyone know about any (jQuery/javascript/etc) compass  available that I can use for a website/webapp?
Thanks

Comment: How would you know which way I'm sitting? All the other things can be sensed from the environment, your computer would have to have a compass in it.

Comment: @Kris.Mitchell [iOS device API for compass](http://tripleodeon.com/2011/10/taking-a-new-device-api-for-a-spin/) [demo](http://jamesgpearce.github.com/compios5/)

Comment: @sachleen Or it's purely for visualisation purposes rather than being relative to the direction you're facing. The wind is still blowing southwest, for example, regardless of whether you're facing east or north.

Comment: @sachleen, he wants to show the direction the wind is coming from. your computer doesn't matter, because if you orient yourself to north, then the wind direction he wants to show is correct.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist That's not how a compass works. There are weather sensors all over the place that services like Google read weather data from.

Comment: @sachleen stop trolling.

Comment: @MichaelDillon ah I get it now. my bad. If you just take a compass face and put a div with an arrow image on it, you can rotate it using [CSS transforms](http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate)

Comment: Sorry for not stating this in my question.... I have sensors to get the wind direction... I just want to display it on the Web..... for that I need a compass widget/API to show the direction.... Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my approach using only CSS. Uses transforms to rotate the needle. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/adb2A/) You can also use the [jQuery Rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) plugin.

HTML

```
<div id="compass">
  <div id="arrow"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#compass {
  width: 380px;
  height: 380px;
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/44nyA.jpg');
  position: relative;
}
#arrow {
  width: 360px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:#F00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(120deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(120deg);

  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#compass:hover #arrow {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 and it's Canvas will make short work of this.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/canvas_drawing_lines.htm

I'm just posting it here for completeness, personally I'd still stick to a javascript library.

Comment: Note to those who arrived here searching for a way to build a dial gauge ... please see my HTML5 answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236814](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236814/wind-direction-on-a-compass-wunderground/36242222#36242222)