# wind direction on a compass wunderground

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

am make weather jquery from wunderground api , and my jquery his working good . but the porblem is in wunderground api the wind direction degrees , iwant get wind degrees on compass and i find in stackoverflow this answer in some Questions :

CSS:

```
#compass {
  width: 380px;
  height: 380px;
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/44nyA.jpg');
  position: relative;
}
#arrow {
  width: 360px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:#F00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(120deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(120deg);

  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#compass:hover #arrow {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
}​
```

html

```
<div id="compass">
  <div id="arrow"></div>
</div>​
```

i want apply this css in my jquery weather but i dont know how . and this demo for this css : http://jsfiddle.net/adb2A/

this is my jquery :

```
 var x = document.getElementById("demo");

 if (navigator.geolocation) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
 } else { 
 x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
 }

 function showPosition(position) {
 var location = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude; 

 jQuery(document).ready(function(weather) {

 $.ajax({
 url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/eb7a37c339cfd624/geolookup/conditions/forecast10day/lang:AR/q/"+location+".json",
 dataType : "jsonp",
success : function(data) {


var html = '<div style="color: black;text-align:right;direction: rtl;">';

html += '<h2>درجة حرارة الان ' + data.current_observation.temp_c + '</h2>'
html += '<h3>شعور بها ' + data.current_observation.feelslike_c + '</h3>'
html += '<h3>الرطوبة ' + data.current_observation.relative_humidity + '</h3>'
html += '<h3>الضغط الجوي ' + data.current_observation.pressure_mb + '</h3>'
html += '<h3>كمية هطول الامطار ' + data.current_observation.precip_today_in + '</h3>'

html += '</div>';

  $("#news").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");

  ///10days///

var dayArray = data.forecast.txt_forecast['forecastday'];

var html = '<div id="10days" style="color: black;text-align:right;direction: rtl;">';
for(var i=0; i<dayArray.length; i+=2)

html += '<div class="container center-block"><div class="row "><div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"><h3>'+data.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday[i]['title']+ " : " +data.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday[i]['fcttext_metric']+'</h3></div>'

html += '</div></div>';

  $("#10").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");


 }
 });
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE 2021**:
The example code no longer runs because the Weather Underground (Wunderground) API was deprecated in 2018. However, the code could be modified to use a different data provider.

### How to build a dial gauge

The question asks how to build a dial gauge to display wind direction information. This code snippet shows you how to create one that looks professional with a minimal amount of coding. It can be easily adapted to other applications and data.

OP originally tried to accomplish this with a lengthy and complex list of CSS transformation. Yet, a much simpler solution is to use the CANVAS tag with a scaled background image and a dynamically positioned indicator needle.

The bare minimum code is shown below. And with a bit of extra styling, as show in the full snippet, you can achieve a professional looking dial gauge for any application.

**TRY THE DEMO**

To view the demo, click "Show code snippet" and then "Run code snippet" (you may need to scroll down to see it). The demo displays the current wind direction for Berlin, Germany. Click the "test" button to animate the gauge.

**CSS**

```
#compass {
  background: url(YourGaugeBackground.jpg); 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function setCompass(degrees) {
      var x, y, r, ctx, radians;
      ctx = window.compass.getContext("2d");
      radians = 0.0174533 * (degrees - 90);
      x = ctx.canvas.width / 2;
      y = ctx.canvas.height / 2; 
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height );
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 10;
      ctx.moveTo(x, y);
      ctx.lineTo(x + r * Math.cos(radians), y + r * Math.sin(radians));
      ctx.stroke();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="compass" height=200 width=200></canvas>
```

```js
function setCompass(degrees) {

  var x, y, r, ctx, radians;
  
  ctx = window.compass.getContext("2d");
  
  // subtract 90 so that north is up then convert to radians
  radians = 0.0174533 * (degrees - 90);
  
  // calc compass centre 
  x = ctx.canvas.width / 2;
  y = ctx.canvas.height / 2; 
  r = x * 0.8;
  
  // clear 
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height );
  ctx.beginPath();

  // optional styling
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 4;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";

  // draw compass needle
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + r * Math.cos(radians), y + r * Math.sin(radians));
  ctx.stroke();

}

// ajax call for city weather data
function getWeatherForecast() {

  var url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/eb7a37c339cfd624/geolookup/conditions/forecast10day/lang:EN/q/Germany/Berlin.json';

  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    window.debug.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, false, '  ');
    $('#status').html(
      //'<img src="' + data.current_observation.icon_url + '">' +
      data.location.city + ', ' +
      data.location.country_name + ': ' +
      data.current_observation.temperature_string + ', ' +
      'Wind ' +
      data.current_observation.wind_string + ', ' +
      data.current_observation.wind_degrees + '°'
    );
    setCompass(data.current_observation.wind_degrees);
  });

}

$('#test').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  var d=0, id = setInterval(function() {
    setCompass( d );
    d += 10;
    if (d > 360) {
      clearInterval(id);
      $('#test').attr('disabled',false);
      getWeatherForecast();
    }
  }, 100);
  
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  getWeatherForecast();
});
```

```css
#compass {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/44nyA.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#debug {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50em;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="test">Test</button> scroll down to view json data<br>
<canvas id="compass" height=200 width=200></canvas>
<div id="status">Berlin, Germany</div>
json data source: <a href="http://api.wunderground.com" target="_blank">Weather Underground</a><br>
<textarea id="debug" spellcheck=false></textarea>
```

Comment: i dont know how i thank you , thank you very much and god safe you .

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing, but I am using ASP.net WebForms and the javascript never gets called. I place the JS above in a file under the \scripts folder and I registered it directly into Site.Master along with the other scripts. But the button does not kick off the script in asp.content. Help